# Not able to store non-numerical characters

Tags: javascript, mysql, database

I can store 12345 in the DB column:

```
<?php $favid = '12345';?>

<img id="button" name="button0" src="images/0.jpg" onclick="addremove('<?php echo $favid;?>')" width="150" height="35">
```

But I can't store if it's:

```
<?php $favid = 'abcdf';?>

<img id="button" name="button0" src="images/0.jpg" onclick="addremove('<?php echo $favid;?>')" width="150" height="35">
```

The column is VARCHAR so it should store both, right? Does the problem lie in **onclick="addremove('abcdf')**? What should I change to be able to store non-numericals?

Comment: you should show us addremove() function

Comment: Both are being treated as strings so that would suggest they should both work the same, unless they are being converted to number types in the `addremove` function, for example.

Comment: This is the snippet from addremove.php: `$favid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['favid']);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ajaxfavourites WHERE user=$user AND favid=$favid");
$matches = mysql_num_rows($query);


if($matches == '0'){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ajaxfavourites (user, favid) VALUES ('$user', '$favid')");

echo "<div class=\"green\">This is a favourite</div>";
}


if($matches != '0'){
mysql_query("DELETE FROM ajaxfavourites WHERE user=$user AND favid=$favid");

echo "<div class=\"red\">This is NOT a favourite</div>";
}`

Comment: The ajax snippet: `xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
if(xmlHttp.readyState!=4){
document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML='<img src="images/spinner.gif">  Wait...';
}
if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlHttp.open("GET",nocacheurl+"&favid="+favid,true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
`

Comment: Could it be this line? `mysql_query("INSERT INTO ajaxfavourites (user, favid) VALUES ('$user', '$favid')");`

Comment: By the way that **$favid** is **12345** or **abcdf**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem (one of several actually) is in:

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ajaxfavourites
 WHERE user=$user AND favid=$favid
```

Here you query $favid without quotes, so the SELECT will only work on numeric values.

The other problem is that your code seems really really really sensitive to SQL injection. Read up on php-pdo (has great and easy to use examples on php.net) on how to make your code more secure.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I figured it out while waiting. Single quotes were missing:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ajaxfavourites WHERE user='$user' AND favid='$favid'");
```

It works like it should now.

And yes, I know that the code is outdated. Will work on that next. Thanks everyone!!